# How to export the output from previous cell to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, export

How can I export the output of this previous cell to a .csv file?
[image]

Comment: Can you output the contents of the dictionary v instead to csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to write a dictionary to a csv file, I recommend pandas for this, you can also use csv but this is faster.

```
import pandas as pd

vm =  {'rs963837': None, 'rs9895661': 'BCAS3', 'rs10277115': None, 'rs62435145': None, 'rs13230509': None, 'rs13230625': None, 'rs11761603': None, 'rs12702509': None}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(vm,orient='index')

print(df)
```

My output looks like this

```
            0
rs963837    None
rs9895661   BCAS3
rs10277115  None
rs62435145  None
rs13230509  None
rs13230625  None
rs11761603  None
rs12702509  None
```

next you can just do the following to save the dataframe as a csv file.

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv',index=True)
```

Comment: I tried the following commands: 

%%capture cap --no-stderr
print(q)

Comment: What is the object you are trying to save?

Comment: The ouput from sys.stdout.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(v, vm[v])) - which has two columns and > 3K rows

Comment: I mean, is it a dictionary ?

Comment: AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-e9d3b1680c7d> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
   1581             if len(data) > 0:
   1582                 # TODO speed up Series case
-> 1583                 if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
   1584                     data = _from_nested_dict(data)
   1585                 else:

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Can you print the contents of your dict and paste it in your code?

Comment: print(vm) looks as follows:

{'rs963837': None, 'rs9895661': 'BCAS3', 'rs10277115': None, 'rs62435145': None, 'rs13230509': None, 'rs13230625': None, 'rs11761603': None, 'rs12702509': None}

Comment: @Mahan the code works for me, i have updated my code.. can you `print(type(vm))` ?

Comment: Hi, here you go - <class 'dict'>

Comment: i think you are passing a set instead of a dictionary into the function

Comment: @Mahan you should be passing vm into the function not d like me, look at the code again, i changed it to match your vm variable